# Want to hide some fields of an object that are being mapped to JSON by Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a User class that I want to map to JSON using Jackson.

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int securityCode;

    // getters and setters
}
```

I map this to a JSON string using -

```
User user = getUserFromDatabase();

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();   
String json =  mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
```

I don't want to map the `securityCode` variable. Is there any way of configuring the mapper so that it ignores this field?

I know I can write custom data mappers or use the Streaming API but I would like to know if it possible to do it through configuration?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34965201/customize-jackson-objectmapper-to-read-custom-annotation-and-mask-fields-annotat

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Jackson works on setters-getters of fields. So, you can just remove getter of field which you want to omit in JSON. ( If you don't need getter at other place.)
2. Or, you can use the `@JsonIgnore` [annotation of Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations) on getter method of that field and you see there in no such key-value pair in resulted JSON.

   ```
   @JsonIgnore
   public int getSecurityCode(){
      return securityCode;
   }
   ```

Comment: Can I hide based on some condition? Say if name is admin then I need to show else hide?

Comment: @foobar did you find any work around for ur case? I have same cases as yours

Comment: I'm also looking for hiding Json serialization of specific properties based on some condition. Did anyone find an answer ?

Comment: I feel if you use Lombok you can use as below,
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)

Answer (score 28):

Adding this here because somebody else may search this again in future, like me. This Answer is an extension to the [Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14708961/6785908)

```
You have two options:

1. Jackson works on setters-getters of fields. So, you can just remove getter of field which you want to omit in JSON. ( If you don't need getter at other place.)

2. Or, you can use the `@JsonIgnore` [annotation of Jackson][1] on getter method of that field and you see there in no such key-value pair in resulted JSON. 

        @JsonIgnore
        public int getSecurityCode(){
           return securityCode;
        }
```

Actually, **newer version of Jackson added READ_ONLY and WRITE_ONLY annotation arguments for JsonProperty**. So you could also do something like this.

```
@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String securityCode;
```

instead of

```
@JsonIgnore
public int getSecurityCode(){
  return securityCode;
}
```

Comment: This a good way of doing it! even if the @JsonIgnore may work but I find this useful and very straight to the point.

Comment: Very, very good answer. But, just for the clarity of options here: `@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String securityCode;` can then as well be `@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
public String securityCode;`.

Answer (score 20):

you also can gather all properties on an annotation class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties( { "applications" })
public MyClass ...

String applications;
```

Comment: This is great option for classes with @Data lombok annotation, because you don't have much control (only access levels) over the generated getters and setters

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to put annotations on your Pojos you can also use [Genson](http://code.google.com/p/genson/).

Here is how you can exclude a field with it without any annotations (you can also use annotations if you want, but you have the choice).

```
Genson genson = new Genson.Builder().exclude("securityCode", User.class).create();
// and then
String json = genson.serialize(user);
```

Comment: Jackson also offers multiple alternatives to annotating your pojo classes directly; see http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations

Answer (score 2):

Field Level:

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    @JsonIgnore
    private int securityCode;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Class Level:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "securityCode" })
public class User {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int securityCode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using GSON you have to mark the field/member declarations as @Expose and use the GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create()

Don't forget to mark your sub classes with @Expose otherwise the fields won't show.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use this.

```
   @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
   private int securityCode;
```

This allows you to set the value of securityCode(especially if you use lombok @Setter) and also prevent the field from showing up in the GET request.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case where I needed some property to be deserialized (JSON to Object) but not serialized (Object to JSON)

First i went for `@JsonIgnore` - it did prevent serialization of unwanted property, but failed to de-serialize it too. Trying `value` attribute didn't help either as it requires some condition.

Finally, working `@JsonProperty` with `access` attribute worked like a charm.