# ObjectMapper adds extra Field to the JSON String

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I have the following problem.

Here is my `Accident` class and the `CommonDomainEntity` class:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Accident extends CommonDomainObject {
    private String status;
    private Date accidentDate;
    private String name;
}

@Data
public abstract class CommonDomainObject {
    public Long id;

    public boolean isNew() {
        return null == getId();
    }
}
```

In my test class I am calling the following:

```
String exp = objMapper.writeValueAsString(accidents);
System.out.println(exp);
ResponseEntity<String> res = restTemplate.getForEntity("/accidents", String.class);

assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, res.getStatusCode());
JSONAssert.assertEquals(exp, res.getBody(), false);
```

It throws the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: [id=2]
Expected: new
but none found
; [id=3]
Expected: new
but none found
```

I already tried to out print the object `exp` to see whats in it, as well as I tried to print what`s in`accidents`.

As you see in the console logs, for some reason **in the `exp` object there is a `new=false` field, and I can`t figure out where this is from.**

This right here is what is in my accidents List

```
Accident(status=pending, accidentDate=null, name=Name), 
Accident(status=closed, accidentDate=null, name=Name)]
```

And this is my `exp` object as JSON

```
[{"id":2,"status":"pending","accidentDate":null,"name":"Name","new":false}, 
{"id":3,"status":"closed","accidentDate":null,"name":"Name","new":false}]
```

Comment: does Accident have another field on it which isn't part of the constructor? what is the rest service actually returning? is there a "new" field in the returned json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `CommonDomainObject.isNew()` method in the abstract class is evaluated as a JSON field by `ObjectMapper`. You must exclude it using jackson anotations.

```
public abstract class CommonDomainObject {
    ...
    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isNew() {
        return null == getId();
    }
}
```

See:

- [Want to hide some fields of an object that are being mapped to JSON by Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14708386/2886891)
- https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations
- https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations

Your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be:

1. Call `objMapper.writeValueAsString()`
2. Check why the resulting JSON string representation contains the `new` field

All the other code is reduntant for the reproduction of your issue :)

Comment: Thanks so much !!! That solved the Issue. Thank you very very much ! That made me go insane for two days :)

Comment: I just updated the Post, I hope everything is alright like this now :) Thanks for your comprehensive answers and your time to fix my Issue.