# Why custom @Exclude not exclude field from serialization

Tags: java, gson

I need to exclude specific fields when serialize/deserialize object to json.

I create my custom annotation:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Exclude {}
```

Use:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Exclude
    private int id;
    @NotNull
    @Exclude
    private String name;
```

And here serialize by Gson:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    json.addProperty("user_name", currentUserName);
    Product product = productEntry.getProduct();
    json.addProperty("product", GsonUtil.gson.toJson(product));
    json.addProperty("quantity", productEntry.getQuantity());
    logger.info("addProductToCart: json = " + json);
```

and here result:

```
addProductToCart: json = {"user_name":"admin@admin.com","product":"{\"id\":0,\"name\":\"My product 1\",\"description\":\"\",\"created\":\"Apr 27, 2020, 4:53:34 PM\",\"price\":1.0,\"currency\":\"USD\",\"images\":[\"url_1\",\"url_2\"]}","quantity":1}
```

Why fields **id, name** not exclude from json?

Comment: Can you refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14708961/8076698 , not sure if it will help or not but if I'm understanding correct, it will be helpful.

Comment: @prashantdoshi28 I was added my answer

Answer (score 1):

you might need to write your custom json serializer for this  as follows:

```
class ExcludeFieldsSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Bean> {

@Override
public void serialize(final Bean value, final JsonGenerator gen, final SerializerProvider serializer) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    gen.writeStartObject();
    try {
        for (final Field aField : Bean.class.getFields()) {
            if (f.isAnnotationPresent(Ignore.class)) {
                gen.writeStringField(aField.getName(), (String) aField.get(value));
            }
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {

    }
    gen.writeEndObject();
}
```

}

use your object mapper to register the same

However, you can also use existing annotations as

```
@Expose (serialize = false, deserialize = false)
```

Here if serialize is true then marked field is written out in the JSON while serializing.

if deserialize is true, hen marked field is deserialized from the JSON.
and

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
    .create();
```

Later you can do gson.toJson(product)

Edit : if Gson object is created as new Gson() and if we try to execute the toJson() and fromJson() methods then @Expose does not have any effect on serialization and deserialization.

Comment: I was added my answer

Comment: @a_subscriber I have also updated my answer. But its great that you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Gson understands `@Expose(serialize = false)`  annotation,

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

    @Expose(serialize = false)
    private int id;
}
```

Comment: I was added my answer

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Exclude {}
```

and when init gson:

public class GsonUtil {

```
  public static GsonBuilder gsonbuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    public static Gson gson;
    public static JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

    static {
        // @Expose -> to exclude specific field when serialize/deserilaize
        gsonbuilder.addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes field) {
                return field.getAnnotation(Exclude.class) != null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        gson = gsonbuilder.create();
    }
}
```

Use:

```
@Entity
    public class Product {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Exclude
        private int id;
```

and now success EXCLUDE specific field.